# Injective or Surjective? please help.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, modular-arithmetic

I have the problem below.

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ (for $m \geq 1$, and $m$ an integer) defined by $x \mapsto [x]$ where $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$ modulo $m$. Is this function injective? Is it surjective? Justify your answers.

My answer to this problem is that for $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, we divide by $m$ sending $x \mapsto [x] $ and this function is indeed injective. i.e. if I let $m=3$ then the equivalence class of $[0]$ is sent to its congruences of $\{\dots,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,\dots\}$.

I would appreciate any help/feedback. Thanks.

Comment: But $f$ doesn't act on an equivalence class, it acts on an integer. What you're thinking of is the identity function of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, not the function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What are the results of $f(0)$ and $f(m)$?

Comment: A function is injective if $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$ but in your case (with $m=3$): $f(2)=f(5)=[2]$ but $2\neq 5$

Comment: @Henry T. This sounds like the definition of well-defined…

Comment: @peterwhy I don’t know what you mean by that

Comment: @math113student No, well defined would be: $x=y \Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$ e.g. the sin is well defined but not injective since $sin(2\pi)=sin(0)$

Comment: What definitions of injective and surjective do you use?

Comment: @Torsten Schoenberg For injective the definition that I use is a function that maps “distinct elements to distinct elements.” And for surjective I’m using the definition that “every B has some element A”.

Comment: @Henry T. Would you mind showing me how to implement that definition into solving this problem?

Comment: @math113student We are using the exact same definition! Let’s return to my example: in $\mathbb{Z}$ 2 and 5 are distinct elements. But the function f then maps them both to the same equivalence class $[2]$ (because when divided by 3 the remainder is in both cases 2) so they aren’t mapped to distinct elements. Then according to your definition the function can’t possibly be injective. However, $f$ is surjective since if you pick any equivalence class $[k]$ then $f(k)$ is mapped to it!

Comment: I wrote an answer based on your correct definition of injective. Your proposed definition of surjective, as it stands, is meaningless. What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Henry T. Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

With your notation, your map sends an integer $x$ to its equivalence class $[x]$ (note there is no "dividing" involved here at all).

As you correctly say, a function is injective if and only if it sends distinct elements to distinct elements.

In your case, that would mean distinct integers get sent to distinct equivalence classes.

Now $0$ and $m$ (and $2m, 3m, ...$) are all distinct integers, right? But do they get sent to distinct equivalence classes?

Comment: They do not get sent to distinct equivalence classes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not injective since $\ker f=\{km|k\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$

Comment: Do you mind explaining?

Comment: $f$ is a homomorphism so $f$ is an injection if and only if $\ker f={e}$,where $e$ is the unit of $\mathbb{Z}$.